# Follow and follower system ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I will develop a system where users can follow each other in ASP.NET MVC. How can I do it?

I've never done many-to-many table before

```
namespace EntityLayer.Concrete
{
    public partial class Follow
    {
        [Key]
        public int FollowID { get;set;}
        
        public int UserOneID { get;set;}

        public int UserTwoID { get;set;}
        
        public bool IsFollowing { get;set;}

        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        public virtual Author user { get; set; }
        public virtual Author user2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you don' t  need so many fields. These should be enough

```
amespace EntityLayer.Concrete
{
    public partial class Follow
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get;set;} //  instead you can make a composit key from AuthorID and FollowerID together

        public int AuthorID { get;set;}
        public int FollowerID { get;set;}

      
        public bool IsFollowing { get;set;} // I am not sure you really need it, only if you want to keep a history

        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        public virtual Author Follower { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```